# How do I print only the first instance of a string in a text file using Python?

Tags: python, text

I am trying to extract data from a .txt file in Python. My goal is to capture the last occurrence of a certain word and show the next line, so I do a reverse () of the text and read from behind. In this case, I search for the word 'MEC', and show the next line, but I capture all occurrences of the word, not the first.

Any idea what I need to do?

Thanks!

This is what my code looks like:

```py
import re

from file_read_backwards import FileReadBackwards

with FileReadBackwards("camdex.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for l in file:
        lines = l

        while line:
            if re.match('MEC', line):
                x = (file.readline())
                x2 = (x.strip('\n'))
                print(x2)
                break
            line = file.readline()
```

The txt file contains this:

```
MEC
29/35
MEC
28,29/35
```

And with my code print this output:

```
28,29/35
29/35
```

And my objetive is print only this:

```
28,29/35
```

Comment: Given the `break` statement, your output doesn't make sense with the shown code: it should only show the last line.

Comment: I've copied your code and your input text, and I can't reproduce your problem: I get only the last line.

Comment: @00 Sorry, I edit the code and the output. I want the last occurrence. I reverse the .txt and the last occurrence is the first now.

Comment: So you now ask a completely different question?

Comment: Add x2 to an array inside the function. Then print the first element of the array

Comment: Just keep the previous line around: if you have a match (a line containing "MEC"), print the previous line.

Comment: `for l in file: lines = l; line = file.readline()` is going to make a mess: you're now essentially stepping through the file with *two* iterators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the result as well. Loop through lines, add the matching lines to an array. Then print the last element.

```
import re
with open("data\camdex.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    result = []
    for line in file:
        if re.match('MEC', line):
            x = file.readline()
            result.append(x.strip('\n'))

print(result[-1])
```

Comment: @ozzrocker95, if it solves your problem, then mark it as the answer. This will keep me motivated :P

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the extra imports and overhead.  Read your file normally, remembering the last line that qualifies.

```
with ("camdex.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("MEC"):
            last = line

print(last[4:-1])    # "4" gets rid of "MEC "; "-1" stops just before the line feed.
```

If the file is very large, then reading backwards makes sense -- seeking to the end and backing up will be faster than *reading* to the end.